# Object name contains more than the maximum prefixes allowed

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, max, prefixes

I have seen a lot of questions about this but I couldn't find the correct answer for me which works.

The object which triggers the problem is like

```
test123.de.company.com.Database.dbo.Table

Test123.de.company.com
```

is the database Server.

> Object name contains more than the maximum prefixes allowed

I have tried to write it like this `[test123.de.company.com].Database.dbo.Table` just like `[test123.de.company.com].[Database].[dbo].[Table]`

Can you tell me what's wrong with this?

Comment: I don't know what is strictly _wrong_ with what you are doing...but why are you using this naming convention for your database objects?  Why not use something shorter?

Comment: I try to join two tables from different db-servers. Isn't this the right way to get access to a table from another server if u type server.database.table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
["test123.de.company.com"].[Database].[dbo].[Table]
```

OP also encountered a new problem after implementing this solution above. OP said:

> Thank you! This worked for me. To be more precise, the join is for a
>   view and if I save/close and then later get back to the design option
>   the quote marks are removed and there is [test123.de.company.com] left
>   over and the error returns. Is there a way to keep them fixed?
>   Otherwise if I change anything I always have to add the quote marks
>   again and again

Then with the help of DaleK that problem also was solved. DaleK:

> Don't use the design option, script it as alter instead

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me.
To be more precise, the join is for a view and if I save/close and then later get back to the design option the quote marks are removed and there is [test123.de.company.com] left over and the error returns.
Is there a way to keep them fixed? Otherwise if I change anything I always have to add the quote marks again and again

Comment: Hi @Chris did this comment from DaleK helped ? Also please, if this is the correct answer to your question please accept it. If you do not know how please ask. Cheers!

Comment: Yes alter helped instead of using the design option, thank you!

Comment: Happy to hear that. Thanks for marking my answer. @DaleK thanks for assistance on the comment. Cheers!